# Google form triggers Google tasks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-tasks

I would like to have a specific field in a response to a Google Form trigger a task creation. I am using a Google form to record when I am paid for a tutoring session. If someone says they would like a receipt after paying me, I would like to have a task created to remind me to send that receipt.

I have seen several add-ons that automate triggers, but I have already built a template in Google Docs I want to use. I didn't see any questions here that related to this particular need.

Comment: 1) question needs coding attempt. 2) see onFormSubmit 3) google advanced services has task api. With this rewrite question if code still has issues

Comment: There is sample code for creating a task at [Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks#add_task)  You will need to [enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)  You already know about triggers,  Add that function, then create an "On Submit" trigger, see if it runs.